# AdminLTE - Register form changing width

Tags: laravel, forms, sass, adminlte

I'm trying to customize adminlte register form but the problem I'm facing is that the width of the form doesn't change even if i delete the form and build one from scratch. And I can't seem to find the scss responsible for this  so I could change it.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can search `register-box` class in your app directory inside Atom text editor it will show your CSS file for a registration form.